# I want to perfectly center font icons inside flex items

Tags: css, flexbox, icons, font-awesome, vertical-alignment

I have a flex container, inside which I have six flex items. I am trying to place anchor tags(child element of flex item) containing font-icons perfectly centered to the flex items.So I decided to set the display property value of flex item to flex.So basically now I have a flex container inside a flex container.Then I set align-items property and justify-content property of inner flex container to center.
The Icons appear to be horizontally centered to the flex items but not vertically centered.I want to get it vertically centered as well.

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  /* css variables declaration*/
  --sqrt-of-three:1.732;
  --width-of-navbar:75%;
  --number-of-navbarelements:5;
}
.navtab{
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: var(--width-of-navbar);
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
.navhexagon{
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: calc(var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements));
  padding-bottom: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 2));/*The math used here helps to maintain the ratio of 2 : square root of 3*/
  background-color: blue;
  /* clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%); */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;

}
.navbar .navhexagon + .navhexagon /*In order to select every navhexagon element except the first one*/
{
margin-left: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) / -4);
}
.navhexagon:nth-child(even)
{ margin-top:calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 4));
  background-color: pink;
}

a{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f9cdb26252.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar">

        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement1">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement2">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-ghost"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement3">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement4">
           <a href="trial3.html">
              <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement5">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement5">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
           </a>
        </div>


    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This will not work since `padding-bottom` is used to set the height of `.navhexagon` but you can absolutely position its content (you may need to change your math to get to the same height).

```css
*{
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body{
  /* css variables declaration*/
  --sqrt-of-three:1.732;
  --width-of-navbar:75%;
  --number-of-navbarelements:5;
}
.navtab{
  width: 100%;
}
.navbar{
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: var(--width-of-navbar);
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}
.navhexagon{
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: calc(var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements));
  padding-bottom: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 2));/*The math used here helps to maintain the ratio of 2 : square root of 3*/
  background-color: blue;
  /* clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%); */
  position: relative;
}
.navhexagon a {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
.navbar .navhexagon + .navhexagon /*In order to select every navhexagon element except the first one*/
{
margin-left: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) / -4);
}
.navhexagon:nth-child(even)
{ margin-top:calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 4));
  background-color: pink;
}

a{
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f9cdb26252.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <body>
      <nav class="navbar">

        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement1">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement2">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-ghost"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement3">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement4">
           <a href="trial3.html">
              <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement5">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>
           </a>
        </div>
        <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement5">
           <a href="trial3.html">
             <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
           </a>
        </div>


    </nav>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because of `padding-bottom` set on `.navhexagon`. You could replace that with padding on top and bottom or a height. The icon will then be centered.

Answer (score 0):

You're using padding to set the height which renders flex alignment properties useless.

Instead of only using `padding-bottom` why not split the difference with `padding-top`;

This:

```
padding-bottom: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 2));
```

Becomes:

```
padding-bottom: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 4));
padding-top: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 4));
```

Increased the denominator by 2.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  /* css variables declaration*/
  --sqrt-of-three: 1.732;
  --width-of-navbar: 75%;
  --number-of-navbarelements: 5;
}

.navtab {
  width: 100%;
}

.navbar {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: var(--width-of-navbar);
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navhexagon {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  flex-basis: calc(var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements));
  padding-bottom: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 4));
  padding-top: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 4));
  background-color: blue;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 50%, 25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%);
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.navbar .navhexagon+.navhexagon
/*In order to select every navhexagon element except the first one*/

{
  margin-left: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) / -4);
}

.navhexagon:nth-child(even) {
  margin-top: calc((var(--width-of-navbar) / var(--number-of-navbarelements)) * (var(--sqrt-of-three) / 4));
  background-color: pink;
}

a {
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f9cdb26252.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement1">
    <a href="trial3.html">
      <i class="fas fa-home"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement2">
    <a href="trial3.html">
      <i class="fas fa-ghost"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement3">
    <a href="trial3.html">
      <i class="fas fa-laptop-code"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement4">
    <a href="trial3.html">
      <i class="fas fa-music"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement5">
    <a href="trial3.html">
      <i class="fas fa-project-diagram"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="navhexagon" id="navelement5">
    <a href="trial3.html">
      <i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i>
    </a>
  </div>
</nav>
```